# Confusing behaviour of overloading

Tags: java, types, overloading

I am experiencing a behaviour that I do not understand related to this code snippet. More precisely, I was expecting the call of `getUniqueCost` method for the case in which the operator is of type `Projection` (that is, when `n.isProjection()` is true) to be calling the method having as signature `private double getUniqueCost(final Projection p)` instead of that having signature `private double getUniqueCost(final Node p)`.

Note that Projection is a subclass of Node.

Here the code for the two aforementioned methods:

```
private double getUniqueCost(final Node n){
    if(n.isScan())
        return getUniqueCost(estimateCardinality(n));
    if(n.isJoin())
        return getUniqueCost((NJoin) n);
    if(n.isUnion())
        return getUniqueCost((Union) n);
    if(n.isMaterialization())
        return getUniqueCost(n.getChildren().iterator().next());        
    if(n.isProjection()){ 
        return getUniqueCost(child.isJoin() ? 
            n.getChildren().iterator().next() : ((Projection) n));
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown node type: " + n.getOperator());
}

private double getUniqueCost(final Projection p){
    return getUniqueCost(estimateCardinality(p)) + 
            getUniqueCost(p.getChildren().iterator().next());
}
```

The only way to actually manage to call the second method was to modify the first method as follows (the omitted code is the same as before):

```
private double getUniqueCost(final Node n){
    [...]
    if(n.isProjection()){ 
        final Node child = n.getChildren().iterator().next();
        if(child.isJoin()){
            return getUniqueCost(child);
        }

        final Projection proj = (Projection) n;
        return getUniqueCost(proj);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown node type: " + n.getOperator());
}
```

Given that the cast is executed before actually calling the method (that is, call by value semantics, where the parameters are evaluated before evaluating the method itself), I was expecting it to be sufficient to call the most specific method (the one accepting a parameter of type `Projection`).

It has been a while since I had a look at the type system of Java, my suspect is that the whole expression `child.isJoin() ? n.getChildren().iterator().next() : ((Projection) n)` is typed as `Node`, due to the left part those type is indeed `Node`.

Does anybody can confirm it? If no, do you have a better understanding of what's going on here?

In addition, is there a way to have a more compact (elegant?) way of writing the second version of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your ternary conditional expression - `child.isJoin() ? n.getChildren().iterator().next() : ((Projection) n)` - is a type that both `n.getChildren().iterator().next()` and `((Projection) n)` can be assigned to. Therefore, if one of them is `Node` and the other `Projection`, assuming `Projection` is a sub-class of `Node`, the type of the expression is `Node`.

Your second snippet can be shortened a bit :

```
    if(child.isJoin()){
        return getUniqueCost(child);
    } else {
        return getUniqueCost((Projection) n);
    }
```

Casting `n` to `Projection` is enough the get the overloaded `getUniqueCost(final Projection p)` method called. You don't need an intermediate variable.

Comment: This is what I had in mind for the static typing of the expression, but I was somehow expecting that at runtime the dynamic typing was a bit more refined, knowing which "branch" is going to be taken. Apparently I was expecting too much. Thanks also for the other tip, that's right.